# FormatException для DataGridViewComboCell

Tags: c#, datagridview

Я использую вот такой метод погрузки данных в comboBox

```
AgeGroup.DataSource = children.newTable("SELECT * FROM agegroup");
AgeGroup.ValueMember = "ID";
AgeGroup.DisplayMember = "agegroup";
```

где, `children` экземпляр класса Table - это мой класс для работы с таблицей
`newTable` - метод этого класса, который получает таблицу по запросу

Таблица называется `Agegroup` и имеет 2 поля: `ID INT` и `Agegroup VARCHAR`

Это так же справедливо для `ComboBoxColumn`
Но нам нужна еще целая таблица и что бы значение `ComboBoxColumn` тоже менялось соответственно

Подключаем таблицу:

```
dtChildren.DataSource = children.newTable("SELECT agegroup.agegroup, 
    childrens.SecondName, childrens.FistName, childrens.FatherName " +
    "FROM childrens " +
    "INNER JOIN agegroup ON childrens.IDAgeGroup = agegroup.ID " +
    "WHERE childrens.IDGroup = '" + dtAttendance.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value + "'");
```

Все работает таблица есть, но `comboBox` не подставляет значение, нужно установить `DataPropertyName` для `ComboBoxColumn`
Заметьте, что первое поле которое мы получаем это - `agegroup`, это поле мы будем использовать в `DataPropertyName`, чтобы значение ComboBox менялось в зависимости от записи 
Подключаю `DataPropertyName`
И все на этом начинается ошибка
При попытке получить таблицу, мы получаем исключение от `DataGridView`:
`System.FormatException: недопустимое значение DataGridViewComboCell`

Все действия происходят в одном методе

Я искал и находил похожие ошибки, но они не подходили для работы с БД

Comment: Посмотрите [How to](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/access-objects-in-a-wf-datagridviewcomboboxcell-drop-down-list). И другие гайды из этой серии (ссылки слева).

Comment: Как вариант, использовать DataSet и два BindingSource: к первому привязан DataGridView, ко второму - ComboBoxColumn. [Пример](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/3437d394-588b-459f-a26e-998d022ae258/-datagridview?forum=fordataru)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение проблемы было простым
 
`AgeGroup.ValueMember` и `DataPropertyName` должны быть одного типа 
Я сам указал на проблему в вопросе, при получении таблицы я получал колонку с типом `VARCHAR`, а `ValueMember`, являлся `int`

Я изменил запрос и получаю теперь заместо `agegroup.agegroup` это `agegroup.IDAgeGroup`, который является `int`